# How to create a Map to store Subject/BehaviorSubject of different data types

Tags: typescript, behaviorsubject, subject-observer

In Typescript, how to create a Map to store Subject/BehaviorSubject of different data types

In one of my services classes, I want to have a Map to store Subject of different data types. (The key of the map is number). How do I declare the Map? Below is the sample code

```
export class EventBusService {
private events: Map<number, Subject<????>>;
constructor() { }
public regsiterEvent<T>(id: number, initial: T): BehaviorSubject<T> {
if (this.events.has(id)) {
  throw new Error('The event id already exist ' + id);
 }

  const subject = new BehaviorSubject<T>(initial);
  this.events.set(id, subject);
  return subject;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `any` for variables that you do not know the type. Or `Object` if you want to cast as object instead.

```
private events: Map<number, Subject<any>>;
```

[Typescript data types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

**EDIT:**

If you want to capture the type you have to use a function that return the type

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
   return arg;
}
var result = identity("hello generics"); // return 'string'
```

I.E. In ajax request

```
function getAsync<T>(url: string): Promise<T[]> {
   return fetch(url).then((response: Response) => response.json());
}
getAsync<Movie>("/movies").then(movies => {
    movies.forEach(movie => {
        console.log(movie.title);
    });
});
```

Or alternatively you can use `T` in an interface declaration like `interface Array<T>` and then cast with that interface.
But you can't use `T` for variable declaration, you have to use `any` instead.

[Typescript Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: Yes the Subject<any> works here, but I'm looking for a solution based on Generics.